# What are the names of the saints mentioned in the Bhaktamal?

Tags: vaishnavism, bhakti, ramanandi

Bhaktamal is a Ramanandi text written in in Braja language by Nabhadas in the seventeenth century. Written in poetry form, the work depicts the lives of more than two hundred Vaishnava saints across all sects. What are the names of these saints mentioned in the Bhaktamal?

Comment: So you expect 200 names in an answer!!

Comment: I don't think it's too broad. I'm just asking for the names. Nothing additional is required. @commonman

Comment: I agree, it’s not broad.  An answer just need to list 200 names from a single source.  It’s a clear question with a well-defined scope.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think writing 200+ names is too broad and a copy-paste type answer only  which benefits very few if any,The book is not a rare one I think.So 200 chapters from a book or lists alike can easily be asked? I differ.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury maybe you can ask for a reference (book + page number) that has the names

Comment: @commonman I don't think writing 200 names from single source would be too broad.  And the Bhaktamal hasn't been translated into English, so it would be useful to get a list of these devotees in English.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I appreciate the devotion of those who want a list of 200+ sants' names.Unfortunately I myself earned the fanatid batdh today.I strongly feel some new batches shuld be created for such Qs and their answers.However I dont have any more time to waste.Keep well.Bye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the names of the all the saints mentioned in the Bhaktamal in these "sample pages" [here](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/m/book/details/sri-bhaktamala-translated-for-first-time-into-english-NAN621/).

[image]
[image]
[image]